# Get language code from samsung keyboard

Tags: android

i am using below code to get input language code from user keyboard

```
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    InputMethodSubtype ims = imm.getCurrentInputMethodSubtype();
    String lanCode = ims.getLocale();
```

but this code works with google keyboard but with Samsung keyboard i am getting same language code "en" even if i change input type to other language, how can i get user's input language code from Samsung keyboard, or is there a method which works on all types of keyboard but i haven't tested this on all keyboard

Comment: what is the error that you are getting. can u add your log?

Comment: i am getting only "en" language code even if i change keyboard input type to other language